# C# How do you get an instance of a COM interface

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop

I've been doing quite a bit of googling trying to find the standard way to get an instance of a COM interface.

Microsoft provides an example of this in their article [*COM Interop Part 1: Client Tutorial*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
// Create an instance of a COM coclass:
FilgraphManager graphManager = new FilgraphManager();

// See if it supports the IMediaControl COM interface. 
// Note that this will throw a System.InvalidCastException if 
// the cast fails. This is equivalent to QueryInterface for 
// COM objects:
IMediaControl mc = (IMediaControl) graphManager;

// Now you call a method on a COM interface: 
mc.Run();
```

However, it appears as though they are instantiating a COM object and casting it to a COM interface.

For the interface I am interested in, `IDesktopWallpaper`, there does not seem to be an implementing COM object to instantiate.

An example I found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/298478-problems-implementing-idesktopwallpaper-com-interface/) defines some class that gets instantiated and then casts it to the interface the same way that the msdn example does:

```
[ComImport, Guid("C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD")]
internal class IDesktopWallpaper
{

}

[Guid("B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B"), //B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface DesktopWallpaperInterface
{
    // declared members
}
```

I'm not understanding what the instantiated object is. It seems like an arbitrary object, it has a `GuidAttribute` which seems to indicate that it is an actual COM object.

Another example i found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3551/C-does-Shell-Part) `System.Type` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` to instantiate an object and then casts it to the interface:

```
IntPtr ptrRet;
SHGetMalloc(out ptrRet);

System.Type mallocType = System.Type.GetType("IMalloc");
Object obj = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(ptrRet,mallocType);
IMalloc pMalloc = (IMalloc)obj;
```

This method seems to be requesting a pointer to an existing instance of the interface. I can't find any methods like `SHGetMalloc` for `IDesktopWallpaper` in the Windows Shell documentation.

### Question

So, long story short, what's the standard way to get an instance of a COM interface?

In the event that there is no one-size-fits-all solution, what are the standard *ways* that one can use to get an instance of a COM interface and in what circumstance is each of these ways most useful?

### Edit

After downloading the Windows 10 SDK and referencing that against the Requirements section of the [IDesktopWallpaper interface documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706946(v=vs.85).aspx), I have discovered that you can look up the MIDL from `Shobjidl.h` and use that in the `GuidAttribute` for your interface declaration and then look up the CLSID from `Shobjidl.idl` and use that in conjunction with `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid)` and `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)` to get an instance of an object that implements `IDesktopWallpaper`.

I also see now that the CLSID is what is used in the second method listed above for the `GuidAttribute` of the seemingly arbitrary object. It seems like this method allows you to mimic managed instantiation of the object by instantiating the class and then casting the instance to the COM interface.

**However**
I am still interested to know if this is the best way to do this and what pros and cons may be associated with this method vs others.

Comment: ...Just to be clear, have you registered your service explicitly?

Comment: @RossBush I'm not sure what that means or how to do it, so I suppose I have not.

Comment: Guess you misunderstand COM architecture. In COM you create instance of a class. And then request some interface that created object supported (implements). Interface is nearly nothing without an object. First of all you must find the object and then request the interface. Sometimes it is done in one language statement.
For your case I found an [example with creating DesktopWallpaper object and requesting IDesktopWallpaper interface](https://github.com/Trellmor/WallpaperManager/blob/master/WallpaperManager/WinAPI/DesktopWallpaper.cs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a pointer to a COM object reference by a variety of methods:

- P/Invoke `CoCreateInstance`
- P/Invoke `CLSIDFromProgID` → `CoCreateInstance`
- P/Invoke `IRunningObjectTable.GetObject`
- `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID` → `Activator.CreateInstance`
- `Type.GetTypeFromProgID` → `Activator.CreateInstance`
- `new SomeType()` where `SomeType` is marked with `ComImport`

`Activator.CreateInstance` and `new SomeType()` eventually hit `CoCreateInstance` (if they do not get intercepted by various in-app-domain stuff).  Calls to `CoCreateInstance` for an out-of-process server will eventually hit `IRunningObjectTable` with a class moniker (I think).  The best option depends on what you are trying to do:

- For an in-process server, just use `ComImport`
- For an out-of-process server that is not implemented in .Net, `ComImport` will work, I would prefer to call `CoCreateInstance` to pass the right `CLSCTX`.
- For a .net implemented out-of-process server implemented in .Net, you must call CoCreateInstance directly to avoid the "optimizations" added by `ComImport` that would result in the server being run in-process
- If you are dealing with a moniker, use `IRunningObjectTable`
- If you are starting out with a ProgID rather than a CLSID, use either `CLSIDFromProgID` or `Type.GetTypeFromProgID`

Regardless of how we get a reference to an object, we start out with `IUnknown` (`object` in .Net), and then have to call `IUnknown->QueryInterface` to get a pointer to a particular interface.  Calling `QueryInterface` in .Net is effected by casting to an interface marked as `ComVisible` (and usually annotated with `GuidAttribute`).

In the example you named, you would end up with:

```
// based off of https://bitbucket.org/ciniml/desktopwallpaper
[ComImport]
[Guid("B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDesktopWallpaper
{
    void SetWallpaper([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string wallpaper);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string GetWallpaper([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string GetMonitorDevicePathAt(uint monitorIndex);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint GetMonitorDevicePathCount();

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    Rect GetMonitorRECT([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID);

    void SetBackgroundColor([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint color);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    uint GetBackgroundColor();

    void SetPosition([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] DesktopWallpaperPosition position);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    DesktopWallpaperPosition GetPosition();

    void SetSlideshow(IntPtr items);

    IntPtr GetSlideshow();

    void SetSlideshowOptions(DesktopSlideshowDirection options, uint slideshowTick);

    void GetSlideshowOptions(out DesktopSlideshowDirection options, out uint slideshowTick);

    void AdvanceSlideshow([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string monitorID, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] DesktopSlideshowDirection direction);

    DesktopSlideshowDirection GetStatus();

    bool Enable();
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD")]
public class DesktopWallpaper
{
}

[Flags]
public enum DesktopSlideshowOptions
{
    None = 0,
    ShuffleImages = 0x01
}

[Flags]
public enum DesktopSlideshowState
{
    None = 0,
    Enabled = 0x01,
    Slideshow = 0x02,
    DisabledByRemoteSession = 0x04
}

public enum DesktopSlideshowDirection
{
    Forward = 0,
    Backward = 1
}

public enum DesktopWallpaperPosition
{
    Center = 0,
    Tile = 1,
    Stretch = 2,
    Fit = 3,
    Fill = 4,
    Span = 5,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

An example use of which would be:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IDesktopWallpaper Wallpaper;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        this.Wallpaper = (IDesktopWallpaper)new DesktopWallpaper();

        uint monitorCount = Wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathCount();
        for (uint i = 0; i < monitorCount; i++)
        {
            lbMonitors.Items.Add(Wallpaper.GetMonitorDevicePathAt(i));
        }
    }

    private void lbMonitors_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = (string)lbMonitors.SelectedItem;

        tbWallpaper.Text = Wallpaper.GetWallpaper(path);
    }
}
```

Which produces the form:

[image: Form showing list of monitors and result of GetWallpaper]

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! After using your answer to dig into some more COM concepts, I think I am writing code that is a COM client (according to the definition given here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835(v=vs.85).aspx), whereas your answer provides details for COM servers. Is there any additional information you think might be helpful in the context of writing a COM client? I have been unable to get the `var wallpaper = (IDesktopWallpaper)new DesktopWallpaper()` method to work. Is this because my code is the COM client and not the server?

Comment: @Thick_propheT, of course.  My answer addresses a COM Client, not a COM server.  A C# COM server may be identified by the presence of `[ComVisible(true)]` attribtues, whereas a C# COM Client will have `[ComImport]` attributes.  I have added a full example of the translated interface and related enums.